# Compile JSP classes - A workflow of errors between java and tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, javac

I was doing a JSP webpage/app within eclipse. Since I had some problems with it, I wanted to change, so I backup my files (*.java and *.jsp) to another folder and forgot about eclipse.

`Builds in eclipse: OK`

Now, to compile my code without using eclipse, I do something like this:

```
javac -d ./Server/WEB-INF/classes/ ./src/tfg/lti/Config/TextFileWorker.java

javac -d ./Server/WEB-INF/classes/ -cp ./Server/WEB-INF/classes/ ./src/tfg/lti/Config/Setup.java

javac -d ./Server/WEB-INF/classes/ -cp ./Server/WEB-INF/classes/ ./src/tfg/lti/UI/Painter.java
```

`Builds with my code: OK`

But then, if I try to open my application on Web Browser, I get from Tomcat:

```
Estado HTTP 500 -

type Informe de Excepción

mensaje

descripción El servidor encontró un error interno () que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: tfg/lti/UI/Painter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (no puedo cargar clase tfg.lti.UI.Painter)
```

Translating the spanish parts:

```
Status HTTP 500 -

type exception report

message

description The server found an internal error () that made it couldn't fill this requeriment

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: tfg/lti/UI/Painter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (can not load the class tfg.lti.UI.Painter)
```

Then, based on [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0), I tried to build it changing the target, something like this (to all files):

```
javac -target 1.5 -d ./Server/WEB-INF/classes/ ./src/tfg/lti/Config/TextFileWorker.java
```

`Notice: the target version was choosen just to try, didn't know what value should be correct`

Problem 1: since I was building it with eclipse before, I don't know which target was being used before, but I thought it should be using the last one (1.7). Now I don't understand why it wasn't. Project setup I guess?

Then, when building it again, I got the next error:

```
javac: target release 1.5 conflicts with default source release 1.7
```

So now, based on [Topic, see last answer please](https://legacy.madewithmarmalade.com/jp/node/56926), an `-source 1.5` was added to javac, having something like:

```
javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -d ./Server/WEB-INF/classes/ ./src/tfg/lti/Config/TextFileWorker.java
```

But then, I obtained the last error:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning
```

So finally, based on [bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649672/bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conjunction-with-source-1-6-3), and "learned" that I can ignore this warning if I'm sure I'm not using anything from the new SDK.

Since I'm NOT, I don't want to ignore it, but still don't know how was eclipse building my project, and **how should I build it in order to be able to run it again on my tomcat server**.

Some data:
`Tomcat server: version 6`
`Java JDK: 1.75`
`java -version output:`

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You are compiling using JDK 7 while running on JDK 6..

Comment: I got a bit confused. How do you know I'm running on JDK 6? (by the way, running on JDK? doesn't it run on JSE? which is version 7 too (I think)). So you mean I'm compiling using JDK7 while tomcat uses JDK6? Even then, this should be fixed compiling with JDK6 as a target, but if I uses -target 1.6 it doesn't works as I expect. What am I understanding wrong? (A bunch of things i think..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it. It was as SMA told me, I was building it with JDK 7, and running it with JDK6. But I didn't know how it works, so I had to look for it.

First, I managed to notice that with [Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/). However, as You can see They had compile with an older version, but I was executing it with the older one.

Then, based on [Change the JDK used by Tomcat](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-to-use-jdk-7/), I modified the JAVA_HOME (it was not even set on the `/etc/default/tomcat6` file) to the JDK7. To do this, I add to the file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75
```

Then restarted tomcat(6).

With these changes done, It finally worked.